# Lazy Loading is not working C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm not able to get the existing database value for Persons class alone.

Here I've provided my BO & entity models. ID is primary key for Test  all the entity and other entities ID is added as foreign key

BO:

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
Test testOri = ctx.Tests.Where(p => p.ID == this.Test.ID).FirstOrDefault();             
if (testOri != null)
{
}

public partial class Test : EntityBase
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Test()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        Persons = new Person();
    }
    [Key]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [XLTargetName(null)]
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    [XLTargetName(null)]
    public virtual Person Persons { get; set; }

    public override void AddToModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasMany(e => e.Events).WithRequired(e => e.Test).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().HasOptional(e => e.Persons).WithRequired(e => e.Test).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

}


public partial class Person : EntityBase
{
    public Person()
    {
        Active = true; //DEFAULT TO ACTIVE
    }

    [Key()]
    public string PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XLTargetName(null)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }

    public override void AddToModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}


public partial class Events : EntityBase
{
    public Events()
    {
        Active = true; //DEFAULT TO ACTIVE
    }

    [Key()]
    public string EventID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string EventDetails { get; set; }


    [XLTargetName(null)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }

    public override void AddToModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Based on the Test ID, I'm able to get the exiting records for Test & Events but not able to get the value for Person. Persons is returning null.Please assist to resolve the same,

Comment: thats not really lazy loading, you should just need to add a `include` into your linq, `Test testOri = ctx.Tests.Where(p => p.ID == this.Test.ID).Include("Person").FirstOrDefault();` I think off the top of my head

Comment: {"A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Test' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Person'."}- Getting this error

Comment: ok let me backtrack. `Test testOri = ctx.Tests.Where(p => p.ID == this.Test.ID).FirstOrDefault();` this line of code doesn't fail but `testOri.Persons` is `null`, is that correct. Forget the include statement for now.

Comment: Yes correct, I'm getting null value

Comment: have you looked in the database to check the test record has an person id associated with it?

Comment: verified and its associated with it

Comment: try `Test testOri = ctx.Tests.Where(p => p.ID == this.Test.ID).Include("Persons").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: still getting Null value.